# Pass a bs4.element.Tag list as a parameter to render html file python flask

Tags: flask, routes, render

I have class bs4.element.Tag List and want to pass as a paramter through render_template to render the other html file . The problem is how to let html file show the proper result instead of the html text.

For example:
The bs4.element.Tag List is probably  like :
tag_list = [`'<h3>Hello</h3>','<h3>I</h3>','<h3>here</h3>'`]
and the render_template function is like:

```
return render_template('target.html',data = tag_list)
```

finally,the target.html is like:

```
{%for i in data%}
   {{i}}
{{%endfor%}}
```

The result is :

```
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <h3>I</h3>
  <h3>here</h3>
```

Expected output:

#### Hello I here

Could anyone tell me how to fix it ? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding `safe`

```
{% for i in data %}
   {{ i|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```